# How to send mails through php script?

Tags: php, email

How can i send mails through the php script??
I am trying to do somthing like this:

```
for($k=0;$k<=$x->length-1;$k++)
{
    for($l=0;$l<=$j-1;$l++)
    {
        if($y->item($k)->nodeValue==$JobNoArr[$l] && $AcceptanceDateArr[$l]=='0000-00-00')
        {   
            //echo  $v->item($k)->nodeValue ;
            $email = $v->item($k)->nodeValue . ",";
            $to = $email;
            $subject = "My subject";
            $txt = "Hello world!";
            $headers = "From: webmaster@example.com" . "\r\n" .
            "CC: someother.valid@email.adr";
            mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me in this issue.

Best
Zeeshan

Comment: So you have some code. How does it behave that differs from how you expect it to behave? What errors are reported?

Comment: Well i am sending email and the mail is going over to google ids but not to yahoo or another domain that i am basically looking for to work.

Comment: $y seems to be the result of a DOMXPath::query() and $JobNoArr/$AcceptanceDateArr could come from a database query, right so far? In that case the nested for-loops "smell" unnecessary. Could you be a bit more specific about the data sources and the way you select certain records (from the xml and the database)?

Comment: my domain name of the From mail address is different from the server's name i am sending my mails from. So it was giving me a problem. It works now when i changed that.

Comment: My mail function looks like this

mail($toUser,$subject,$body,$headers, "-fseema.zeeshan@servername.com")

there is a -f in front of the from mail address

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I strongly advise against sending mail using PHP's `mail()` function. Composing valid emails and delivering them successfully is trickier than it seems at first glance. There is encoding, putting parts together, validation & sanitation, error reporting (more than `bool mail(...)`), support for authentication and on and on ... The `mail()` function does not offer any of these things.

Try [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org) or similar. You can configure it to use PHP's `mail()` function and so much more. I highly recommend it.

Comment: SwiftMailer is rather nice, we make our end users use that now because the mail() function on Windows PHP is so broken.

Comment: The mail function on Windows PHP is _not_ broken. I use it all the time.

Comment: notepad.exe isn't broken either, still it's not my first choice for C# development.

Answer (score 6):

You're trying too much all at once. Try going one step at a time. First send a simple email, with hard-coded parameters to get that working, then troubleshoot it within the context of your nested loops.

Comment: my code works for a few domains, like google.. but not all of them.

Comment: You may be hitting spam-filters, etc.

Answer (score 5):

the problem is mail function is very unreliable, especially when sending large amount of emails.

i would recommend looking into PHPmailer library (uses direct SMTP connection):
http://phpmailer.codeworxtech.com/

Answer (score 4):

The code (the inner most block) looks correct.  Make sure your environment is setup correctly.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.setup.php

Answer (score 3):

first do

```
echo $result = mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
```

and see what u get , error ?

I recommend to use a class such phpMailer

why you have comma in the end of ths line ?

```
$email = $v->item($k)->nodeValue . ",";
```

you send to one mail every time.

Answer (score 2):

php-s mail function uses sendmail as a MTA, so if some mails go through and some not, I would look at sendmail's log for errors.

Comment: Not really. PHP uses the sendmail API. Any self-respecting MTA on Unix/Linux can emulate sendmail through a wrapper.

Comment: Correct. Still, my point is that mail sent through PHPs mail function goes out through the system mailer and for me, that would be the first place to look for errors.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a shared web host, or your home computer, the main domain for the server will be something like

```
server.your-isp-or-host.com
```

The spam filter will then see the email claiming to be from

```
yourdomain.com
```

when it really came from the first address, and would then delete it.

This would explain the hit-and-miss nature of your error.

If you are on a dedicated server, or a static IP pointing to your home computer with properly set up DNS, the above does not apply.

Answer (score 1):

if it works sending emails to gmail then it should work fine sending emails to yahoo too

you may find that the issue is not the sending of the emails, but maybe yahoo is marking them as spam or blocking them at the gateway

i notice you are appending a comma to the end of the email address, what is the point of that ?

there may be other problems, are your loops correct, are they covering all the cases you expected.

are you sending thousands of emails ? can your mta handle the rate at which you are putting emails into the queue

is your script hitting max_execution time and stopping ?

Comment: none of the above.. my script is working fine for gmail, and other mail servers, but not working for yahoo .. I am not sending thousands of mail, but ya a couple hundred.