# PHP - how to do i send mail using my domain Dreamhost.com

Tags: php, email

I want a PHP code to send a mail using dreamhost.com what will be the code........
I know that SMTP must be use to send the mail.
So please anyone who have code please give it.......

Comment: Are you sure you can't just use mail() command to send the mail you want?

Comment: my log4php mailing appender on my Dreamhost account only started sending mail once the from address domain was the same as the domain being hosted.

Answer (score 3):

Try this: [Use PHP mail to send via smtp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825414/use-php-mail-to-send-via-smtp)

Comment: +1. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058826/how-to-send-mails-through-php-script/1058856#1058856

Answer (score 1):

If you use a library like [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org) it's quite simple. Have a look at their [docs](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/smtp-howto).

Comment: Dreamhost disables fsockopen, which is apparently used by Swiftmailer to send mail SMTP mail.

Answer (score 0):

The best option would be to use the [PEAR Mail Package](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail) (Here's [how to use it](http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/PHP_Email_SMTP_Authentication.htm)) which may be already installed on your server. (Especially if you are using xampp or something similar.)

You can also edit your [php.ini](http://www.geeklog.net/faqman/index.php?op=view&t=53) file like this:

```
 [mail function]
 SMTP = smtp.dreamhost.com
 sendmail_from = me@dreamhost.com
```